# My programs works in Visual Studio but not in other IDE example AWS Cloud 9

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I created my program in Visual Studio, it works perfectly the input / output etc. are all correct. When I run it in AWS Cloud 9 or Mirmir I get the same error message, What does this mean? How should I modify it to work in AWS?   I thought C++ codes work in all IDE which supports C++. The errors are:

1. In constructor ‘Departments::Departments(int, char*, char*)’:
   error: ‘strcpy_s’ was not declared in this scope
   strcpy_s(Departmentname, nameOfDepartment);
   ^
2. In constructor ‘Employee::Employee(int, char*, double, double, int)’:
   error: ‘strcpy_s’ was not declared in this scope
   strcpy_s(emploeename, nameOfTheEmployee);

   ```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    #include <sstream>
    #include <fstream>

    using namespace std;
    const int SizeForString = 100;
    char deptartmentRecordFileName[100] = "departments.dat ";
    char employeeRecordFileName[100] = "employees.dat";



    struct  Departments {
        int DepartmentID;
        char Departmentname[SizeForString];
        char DepartmentHeadName[SizeForString];
        Departments()
        {

        }

        Departments(int idOfTheDepartment, char nameOfDepartment[], char headNameOfDepartment[])
        {

            DepartmentID = idOfTheDepartment;
            strcpy_s(Departmentname, nameOfDepartment);
            strcpy_s(DepartmentHeadName, headNameOfDepartment);
        }





    };






    struct Employee {


        int employeeID;
        char emploeename[SizeForString];
        double employeesalary;
        double employeeage;
        int employeeDepartmentID;
        Employee() 
        {
        }


        Employee(int idOfTheEmployee, char nameOfTheEmployee[], double salaryOfTheEmployee, double ageOfTheEmployee, int departmentId)

        {
            employeeID = idOfTheEmployee;
            strcpy_s(emploeename, nameOfTheEmployee);
            employeesalary = salaryOfTheEmployee;
            employeeage = ageOfTheEmployee;
            employeeDepartmentID = departmentId;

        }






    };






    bool DepartmentIdCheck (int id)
    {
        Departments temp;
        ifstream myfile1(deptartmentRecordFileName, ios::in | ios::binary | ios::app);
        if (!myfile1)
        {
            cout << "Error To Open File.\n";
            return false;
        }
        while (myfile1.read((char*)&temp, sizeof(Departments)))
        {
            if (temp.DepartmentID == id)
            {
                myfile1.close();
                return true;

            }
        }
        myfile1.close();
        return false;

    }





    bool checkIDEmplyee (int id)
    {
        Employee temp;
        ifstream myfile1(employeeRecordFileName, ios::in | ios::binary | ios::app);
        if (!myfile1)
        {


            cout << "Error To Open File.\n";
            return false;

        }
        while (myfile1.read((char*)&temp, sizeof(Employee)))
        {
            if (temp.employeeID == id)
            {
                myfile1.close();
                return true;

            }
        }
        myfile1.close();
        return false;

    }





    void writeDepartmentData(Departments temp)
    {

        ofstream myfile1(deptartmentRecordFileName, ios::out | ios::binary | ios::app);
        if (!myfile1)
        {
            cout << "Error To Open File.\n";
            return;


        }

        myfile1.write((char*)&temp, sizeof(Departments));
        myfile1.close();;
    }




    void writeEmployeeData(Employee temp)
    {
        ofstream myfile1(employeeRecordFileName, ios::out | ios::binary | ios::app);
        if (!myfile1)
        {

            cout << "Error To Open File.\n";
            return;
        }

        myfile1.write((char*)&temp, sizeof(Employee));
        myfile1.close();



    }





    void createReport()
    {
        double totalSalary = 0;
        Departments depTemp;
        ifstream myfile1(deptartmentRecordFileName, ios::in | ios::binary | ios::app);
        if (!myfile1)
        {


            cout << "Error To Open File.\n";
            return;

        }





        while (myfile1.read((char*)&depTemp, sizeof(Departments)))
        {

            Employee empTemp;
            ifstream myfile2(employeeRecordFileName, ios::in | ios::binary | ios::app);
            while (myfile2.read((char*)&empTemp, sizeof(Employee)))
            {


                if (!myfile1)
                {
                    cout << "Error To Open File.\n";
                    return;
                }



                if (depTemp.DepartmentID == empTemp.employeeDepartmentID)
                {
                    totalSalary += empTemp.employeesalary;
                }
            }

            cout << "Dept       : " << depTemp.Departmentname << endl;
            cout << "Total Salary : $" << totalSalary << endl << endl;


            myfile2.close();
            totalSalary = 0;
        }
        myfile1.close();

    }





    int main() 
    {   
        int choice = 0;

        while (choice != 4) 
        {
            cout << "\nHuman Resources Menu";

            cout << "\n1. Create Department"
                "\n2. Create Employee"
                "\n3. Display Salary Report"
                "\n4. -- Quit -- " << endl;

            cout << "Please make a selection : ";
            cin >> choice;

            if (choice == 1)
            {
                int deptIdInput;
                char nameDeptInput[SizeForString];
                char headNameInput[SizeForString];

                cout << "Please Enter Department Details:" << endl;
                cout << "Department ID : ";
                cin >> deptIdInput;



                bool IdExit = DepartmentIdCheck (deptIdInput);




                if (IdExit)
                {
                    cout << "Value must be unique!" << endl;
                    continue;

                }

                cout << "Department Name : ";
                cin >> nameDeptInput, SizeForString;
                cout << "Head of Department : ";
                cin >> headNameInput;
                Departments d(deptIdInput, nameDeptInput, headNameInput);
                writeDepartmentData(d);

            }





            else if (choice == 2)
            {
                int idEmploy;
                char nameEmploy[SizeForString];
                double salaryEmploy;
                double ageEmploy;
                int departmentIdForEmploy;

                cout << "Please Enter Employee Details:" << endl;
                cout << "Employee ID : ";
                cin >> idEmploy;

                bool IdExit = checkIDEmplyee (idEmploy);


                if (IdExit)
                {
                    cout << "Value must be unique !" << endl;
                    continue;

                }



                cout << "Employee Name : ";
                cin >> nameEmploy;
                cin.ignore();

                cout << "Salary: $";
                cin >> salaryEmploy;

                cout << "Age : ";
                cin >> ageEmploy;

                cout << "Department ID : ";
                cin >> departmentIdForEmploy;




                bool foundId = DepartmentIdCheck (departmentIdForEmploy);

                while (!foundId)
                {
                    cout << "Please enter a valid department ID  : ";
                    cin >> departmentIdForEmploy;
                    foundId = DepartmentIdCheck (departmentIdForEmploy);
                }
                Employee e(idEmploy, nameEmploy, salaryEmploy, ageEmploy, departmentIdForEmploy);
                writeEmployeeData(e);
            }
            else if (choice == 3)
            {
                createReport();
            }
            else if (choice != 4)
            {
                cout << "Please enter a valid choice" << endl;

            }

        }
    }
   ```

Comment: You can use `strcpy` but in Visual Studio define `_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS`

Answer (score 0):

Your Visual Studio IDE may have loaded in libraries for you that your other IDEs do not. It looks like [strcpy](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcpy/) is part of the <cstring> library. You will need to `#include <cstring>` to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio runs on Windows while Cloud9 runs on linux. They use different compilers with different standard libraries.